# Visualizing the equation for separating hyperplane

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bias, linearly-separable

I was wondering if I can visualize with the example the fact that for all points $x$ on the separating hyperplane, the following equation holds true:

$$w^T.x+w_0=0\quad\quad\quad \text{... equation (1)}$$

Here, $w$ is a weight vector and $w_0$ is a bias term (perpendicular distance of the separating hyperplane from the origin) defining separating hyperplane.
I was trying to visualize in 2D space. In 2D, the separating hyperplane is nothing but the decision boundary. So, I took following example: $w=[1\quad 2], w_0=\Vert w\Vert=\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt{5}$ and $x=[0\quad 2.5]$. (Check at the bottom of the post, how I came up with these.)

[image]

But I don't find this example make above equation true: $$\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2.5 \end{bmatrix}-\sqrt{5}=5-\sqrt{5}\neq 0}$$

However, I then realized that making $w$ a unit vector makes equation (1) true:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{5} \\2/\sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2.5 \end{bmatrix}-\sqrt{5}=\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5}= 0$$

[image]

So, I have following few related questions:

**Q1**. Does equation (1) applies "only to" unit weight vector? (In read some texts which scale this equation to make $w$ a unit vector) Is there any way to make equation (1) work for non-unit weight vector?

**Q2.** Are weight vectors always considered to be unit vectors? (that is even during actual implementation, do they turn out to be unit vector?)

---

#### How I come up with the graph

First, assumed $w=[1\quad 2]$. The slope of the vector will be $2$. So to plot line passing through the vector and origin, I plotted $y=2x$. The slope of the line perpendicular to this line will be negative inverse of slope of this line, that is it will be $-1/2$. So to plot a line (separating plane or decision boundary) perpendicular to $y=2x$ and not passing through the origin, but through $y=2.5$, I plotted a line $y=-\frac{1}{2}x+2.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. The equation is still valid if $\|w\|\neq1$, but the interpretation of $w_1$ as the (signed) distance from the origin is not.

Q2. You haven't specified a learning algorithm, but for example with SVM, the popular libsvm formulates the problem(s) with $w$ *not* a unit vector, instead scaling so that $\|w\|$ gives the margin width. But also, quite often under the hood it solves the dual problem instead.